# What would happen if i move a rectangle shaped conductor in a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, induction

[image]

I know that in situation II there will be a induction current; and there will be no induction current because of the constant magnetic flux in situation I; but when we move a linear conductor in a constant magnetic field it polarizes because of the charge.

In situation I why conductor does not get polarized and cause an induction EMF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does infact induce emf into the rectangular loop. That emf just doesn't flow current.
Call the left side of your rectangle side A and the right side as side B (in case I).

The side B will induce emf with the upper point as the higher potential.
The side A will also induce emf again with the upper point as higher potential.

Now when you look it as a whole the net emf is zero as the induced emf from side A is cancelled by side B. So even though emf is induced in the individual sides no current flows through them.
PS- If you connect a resistance using the upper and lower sides then current will flow in the resistor even in case 1

Comment: Does higher potential means positive pole ?

Comment: Yeah!!!!!!!!!!!